# How do I find the message options button on whatsapp with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I want to automate the action of deleting some messages, how can I find a down-context button to delete?

Here's the code. The error is that I can't find the down-context to delete the message
**btn_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="down-context"]')**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
```

Python Constants

```
WPP_URL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
NEW_CHAT = '//*[@id="side"]/header/div[2]/div/span/div[2]/div/span'
SEARCH_CONTACT = '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]'
FIRST_CONTACT= '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span'
TYPE_MSG = '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]'
SEND_BUTTON = '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button/span'
OPTION_BTN = '//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]/div/div/div'
DELETE_BTN = '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/span[4]/div/ul/div/li[5]'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(WPP_URL)

def send_message(contato,mensagem):
    new_msg_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(NEW_CHAT)
    new_msg_button.click()
    sleep(1)
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath(SEARCH_CONTACT)
    search_field.click()
    search_field.send_keys(contato)
    sleep(1)
    first_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath(FIRST_CONTACT)
    first_contact.click()
    sleep(1.5)
    type_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath(TYPE_MSG)
    type_field.click()
    type_field.send_keys(mensagem)
    send_msg= driver.find_element_by_xpath(SEND_BUTTON)
    send_msg.click()
    sleep(1)
```

Delete message function

```
def delete_message(contato):
    new_msg_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(NEW_CHAT)
    new_msg_button.click()
    sleep(1)
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath(SEARCH_CONTACT)
    search_field.click()
    search_field.send_keys(contato)
    sleep(1)
    first_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath(FIRST_CONTACT)
    first_contact.click()
    sleep(3)
    **btn_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="down-context"]')**
    btn_option.click()
    sleep(2)
    btn_delete = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_11srW _2xxet _3lsW-")
    btn_delete.click()

msg_padrão = "Olá {}, tudo bem com você? Seu codigo de rastreamento é {}"
lista_contatos = ["João bot","Júlia bot","João bot", "Julia bot"]
lista_codigos = ["12312513","534534743","62354236323","234234226"]


for contato,codigo in zip(lista_contatos,lista_codigos):
    send_message(contato,msg_padrão.format(contato,codigo))

contatos_recentes = ["João bot","Júlia bot"]    
for contato in contatos_recentes:
    delete_message(contato)
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps to delete your the last sent message are:
You need to open the dialog by clicking this button `(//div[contains(@class,'message-out')]//div[@role='button'])[last()]`
However, you have to hover over this element to click on it. So you need to import this:
`from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`
and then

```
btn_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'message-out')]//div[@role='button'])[last()]")  
hover = ActionChains(firefox).move_to_element(btn_option)
hover.perform()   
btn_option.click()
```

Then select `Delete message` option by clicking on `//div[@aria-label='Delete message']` element.
Now you can click `(//div[@data-animate-modal-popup='true']//div[@role='button'])[last()]` if you wish to delete that message for everyone or `(//div[@data-animate-modal-popup='true']//div[@role='button'])[1]` to delete it for you only.
BTW, I see you are using very long and complex `css` selectors. It's not the best practice.

Comment: It didn't work. The first code `btn_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'message-out')]//div[@role='button'])[last()]")    btn_option.click()` stopped here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZhEukG8aWZXG2JAyc2JZqpKIEz7-5GG/view?usp=sharing for the second line I received this error NoSuchElementException -> second line:  `btn_option_delete = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Delete message']")     btn_option_delete.click()`

Comment: See my updated answer. I hope now it will work. I can't check this on my machine, I even don't have python on it these days :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't learn how to solve with your help. I just made this modification  It's your code: `btn_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'message-out')]//div[@role='button'])[last()]")  
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(btn_option)
    hover.perform()` I added the address of the options box: 
     `dialog_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[16]/div[1]/div/span[2]/div')
    dialog_click.click()`

Answer (score 0):

The final code to delete:

```
def delete_message(contato):
#Open new chat on whatsapp web
new_msg_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(NEW_CHAT)
new_msg_button.click()
sleep(1)
#Search the contact
search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath(SEARCH_CONTACT)
search_field.click()
search_field.send_keys(contato)
sleep(1)
#Click on the firts contact with the name that I told
first_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath(FIRST_CONTACT)
first_contact.click()
sleep(2)
#open the dialog by clicking this button
btn_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'message-out')]//div[@role='button'])[last()]")  
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(btn_option)
hover.perform()
dialog_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[16]/div[1]/div/span[2]/div')
dialog_click.click()
sleep(1.5)
#Then select Delete message option by clicking on
btn_option_delete = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/span[4]/div/ul/div/li[5]')
btn_option_delete.click()
sleep(2)
#delete that message for everyone
delete = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@data-animate-modal-popup='true']//div[@role='button'])[last()]")
delete.click()
sleep(2)
#Confirm the option
finish = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div')
finish.click()
```